# Excel: summing cells based on the presence of value in adjacent column

Tags: excel

I happened upon this forum while looking to solve an Excel dilemma:

I have an accounting spreadsheet where different line item charges are classified in various categories by a letter (e.g. "R" in column B means the amount listed in column A is for "Rent").

What I want to do is total the values in column A based on like values in column B (total up all of the rent payments).

Can someone suggest a function(s) that would work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the SUMIF() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sumif() function for single criteria or you can use SUMIFS() for multiple criteria. Please see below screenshot.

```
=SUMIF(B2:B7,"R",A2:A7)

=SUMIFS(A2:A7,B2:B7,"R")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This is just the function I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The formula that you want is SUMIF() or SUMIFS() if you have multiple criteria.

It's described pretty clearly here. 
http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/count-sum-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for your help!